# Need help with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 \, dx}{x^4+2a^2x^2+b^4}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm having trouble trying to evaluate this definite integral. Mathematica didn't help much.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 \, dx}{x^4+2a^2x^2+b^4}$$
where $a$, $b$ $\in \Bbb R^+$.

Is it possible to solve it analytically? What methods should I try?

Comment: It's not very nice looking.  However, you can find the poles in the denominator and you might be able to use a contour integral in the upper half-plane and the residue theorem.  No easy u-sub here.

Comment: I have two choices for you.  Use complex analysis and apply the Cauchy integral formula.  Or, break it up into partial fractions, and apply inverse tan substitutions.

Comment: Well, here's what [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int+_{-\infty+}^{\infty+}\:\frac{x^2dx}{x^4%2B2a^2x^2%2Bb^4}) gives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let we set $\lambda=\frac{b}{a}$ . We want:
$$ I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2+(b^4-a^4)} = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+1)^2+(\lambda^4-1)}$$
and assuming that $\zeta_1(\lambda),\zeta_2(\lambda)$ are the roots of $(x^2+1)^2=1-\lambda^4$ in the upper half-plane, the residue theorem gives:
$$ I(a,b)=\frac{2\pi i}{a}\sum_{j=1}^{2}\text{Res}\left(\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2+(\lambda^4-1)},x=\zeta_j\right)$$
that by De l'Hopital theorem simplifies to:
$$ I(a,b)=\frac{\pi i}{2a}\sum_{j=1}^{2}\frac{\zeta_j}{1+\zeta_j^2}$$
where $1+\zeta_j^2$ is either $\sqrt{\lambda^4-1}$ or $-\sqrt{\lambda^4-1}$, $\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\overline{\zeta}_1+\overline{\zeta}_2=0$ by Viète's theorem and $\zeta_1-\zeta_2$ is deeply related with the discriminant of $(x^2+1)^2+(\lambda^4-1)$. Can you finish from here? I am getting:

> $$ I(a,b) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}}}. $$

Comment: This seems correct to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

We can write the integrand as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{x^4+2a^2x^2+b^4}&=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4})(x^2+a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4})}\\\\
&=\frac{A}{x^2+a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}+\frac{B}{x^2+a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}
\end{align}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are given respectively by

$$A=\frac{-a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}$$

and

$$B=\frac{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}$$

Therefore, we find that for $a>b>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+2a^2x^2+b^4}\,dx&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+2a^2x^2+b^4}\,dx\\\\
&=2A\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\,dx+2B\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi A}{\sqrt{a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}}+\frac{\pi B}{\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\left(\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}-\sqrt{a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\left(\sqrt{2(a^2-b^2)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

> Note that for $b>a>0$, result of the preceding development is unaltered.  One needs only to proceed with caution when evaluating the integrals, $\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2\pm \sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\,dx$ due to the complex constants $a^2\pm \sqrt{a^4-b^4}$.
>
> For the case $a=b>0$, the result of the preceding developing is unaltered.  The integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx$ can easily be evaluated enforcing the substitution $x\to a\tan(x)$.

Comment: Good answer, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Just one small doubt, did you use that $a>b$ in this step? $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\left(\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}-\sqrt{a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\left(\sqrt{2(a^2-b^2)}\right)$. I can't figure it out for myself.

Comment: @guest_user Set $x=\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}-\sqrt{a^2-\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}$.  Square both sides and simplify to obtain $x^2=2a^2-2\sqrt{b^4}=2(a^2-b^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}}$ and $\ds{p \equiv \pars{a/b}^{2}}$,
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{2}\,\dd x \over x^{4} + 2a^{2}x^{2} + b^{4}}}
& =
{1 \over \verts{b}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{2}\,\dd x \over x^{4} + 2px^{2} + 1} =
{1 \over \verts{b}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1}
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over \verts{b}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over \pars{x - x_{+}}\pars{x - x_{-}}}
\end{align}

where $\braces{x_{\pm}}$ are the roots of $x^{2} + 2px + 1 = 0$ which are given by
$x_{\pm} = -p \pm \root{p^{2} - 1}$. The integration can be performed along a *key-hole contour* which takes into account the branch-cut of
$z^{1/2} = \verts{z}^{1/2}\exp\pars{\ic\phi/2}\,,\ z \not= 0\,,\
0 < \phi < 2\pi$. Then,

- ${\large p < 1}$

  The roots are given by $x_{\pm} = -p \pm \ic\root{1 - p^{2}}$ with $\verts{x_{\pm}} = 1$.

  \begin{align}
  2\pi\ic\bracks{%
  {\verts{x_{+}}^{1/2}\expo{\ic\phi_{+}/2} \over x_{+} - x_{-}} +
  {\verts{x_{-}}^{1/2}\expo{\ic\phi_{-}/2} \over x_{-} - x_{+}}} & =
  \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1} +
  \int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{1/2}\expo{\ic\pi}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1}
  \\[3mm] 
  \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1} & =
  {\pi \over 2\root{1 - p^{2}}}\pars{\expo{\ic\phi_{+}/2} - \expo{\ic\phi_{-}/2}}
  \\[3mm]
  \phi_{+} = {\pi \over 2} + \delta\phi\,,\quad
  \phi_{-} = {3\pi \over 2} - \delta\phi\,,\quad &
  \delta\phi \equiv \arctan\pars{{p \over \root{1 - p^{2}}}}
  \end{align}

  \begin{align}
  \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1} & =
  {\pi \over 2\root{1 - p^{2}}}\pars{%
  \expo{\ic\pi/4}\expo{\ic\delta\phi/2} -
  \expo{3\ic\pi/4}\expo{-\ic\delta\phi/2}}
  \\[3mm] & =
  {\pi \over 2\root{1 - p^{2}}}\bracks{%
  {1 + \ic \over \root{2}}\,\expo{\ic\delta\phi/2} -
  {-1 + \ic \over \root{2}}\,\expo{-\ic\delta\phi/2}}
  \\[3mm] & =
  {\root{2}\pi \over 2\root{1 - p^{2}}}\bracks{%
  \cos\pars{\delta\phi \over 2} - \sin\pars{\delta\phi \over 2}}
  \\[3mm] & =
  {\root{2}\pi \over 2\root{1 - p^{2}}}\bracks{%
  \root{{1 + \cos\pars{\delta\phi} \over 2}} -
  \root{{1 - \cos\pars{\delta\phi}} \over 2}}
  \end{align}

  However,
  $\ds{\cos\pars{\delta\phi} = {1 \over \root{\tan^{2}\pars{\delta\phi} + 1}}
       = \root{1 - p^{2}} = {\root{b^{2} - a^{2}} \over \verts{b}}}$:
  \begin{align}
  \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\dd x \over x^{2} + 2px + 1} & =
  {\pi\verts{b}^{1/2} \over 2\root{b^{2} - a^{2}}}\bracks{%
  \root{\verts{b} + \root{b^{2} - a^{2}}} -
  \root{\verts{b} - \root{b^{2} - a^{2}}}}
  \end{align}
- ${\large p > 1}$. Both roots are negative:
  $x_{\pm} = -p \pm \root{p^{2} - 1}$. `The calculation is similar to the previous one`.